# C# MySql CREATE USER

Tags: c#, mysql, createuser

I was trying to make a registration statement with C#. Obviously I couldn't make it. I don't exactly know what the problem is. With that said here is a snippet:

```
MySqlConnection Connection = 
 new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;UID=root;");
MySqlCommand Command = 
 new MySqlCommand("CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' 
 IDENTIFIED BY 'superpassword';", Connection);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What error do you get from this command?

Comment: Ouh that's hard to say. My exception-message outputs in german. I'll try to translate:

The Index based on 0(null) must be greater or equal Null and less than the size of the argumentlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before executing the command, you need to open the connection

```
using(MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;UID=root;"))
using(MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'superpassword';", Connection))
{
    Connection.Open();
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Do not forget to enclose the disposable commands in a Using Statement

**EDIT** Looking at your code (why don't you put here immediately?) it is clear where is the error

this line

```
this.COMMAND = String.Format("CREATE USER '{0}'@'{1}' IDENTIFIED BY '{3}';", username, host, password);
```

should be

```
this.COMMAND = String.Format("CREATE USER '{0}'@'{1}' IDENTIFIED BY '{2}';", username, host, password);
```

There are three parameters passed to the string format, so the indexes to be used for the placeholders in the string.format are 0, 1 and 2.
You used 3 for the password and this gives the out of range exception

Comment: Oh, sorry almost forgot that. thanks ;)
But I still have the problem. Connection.Open(); didn't fix it :(

I close my connection with
if(Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open){ Connection.Close();}
But I think it does pretty the same :)

Comment: What is the error message? It is raised on the Command.ExecuteNonQuery line?. I have tested the same code here and I don't have any error here

Comment: Do I need to specify it if I just want to Create a MySql-User?
If I type this command into PHPMyAdmin without selecting a certain Database it creates a new user without problems.

Comment: No, I tested it and you don't need it

Comment: See here to see a more detailed snippet. I made a Class which has some basic MySql functions....so don't wonder ^_^
http://pastebin.com/1YQLT9cJ

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Ohh...I think I don't need to explain how dump I feel in this situation.... >.<

However, and It finally works now thanks to you sir :)