# Usage of MySQL Parameter for creating new user

Tags: c#, mysql

So I am using a MySQL Server version 8.0.16 and if I try to let dynamically create a new user, i do receive a Error message what says: >>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax. to use near '$password' at line 1<<.

What i can't understand, becouse if i replace the Parameters with the actual value and try it with the shell it works perfectly. I let my code connect as root so and checked if the connection is open what it is. So if I stepped into the code and checked if the parameters are correct everything looked fine. I also added >>'<< at the beginning and end of thext strings that should replace the parameters but it didn't changed the error or what happened.

```
public bool CreateNewUser(string name, string password, string host)
{
   string query = "CREATE USER $name@$host IDENTIFIED BY $password;";
   List<MySqlParameter> mies = new List<MySqlParameter>
   {
      new MySqlParameter("$name", name),
      new MySqlParameter("$password", password),
      new MySqlParameter("$host", host)
   };

   return InsertIntoQuery(query, mies);
}

//The InsertIntoQuery looks like this

private bool InsertIntoQuery(string sql, List<MySqlParameter> sqlParameters = null)
{
   bool retBl = false;
   try
   {
      using (var SqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr))
      {
         SqlConnection.Open();
         using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, SqlConnection))
         {
            if (sqlParameters != null)
               foreach (var item in sqlParameters)
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.ParameterName, item.Value);
            cmd.Prepare();
            var retValNonQuery = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            retBl = (retValNonQuery > 0) ? true : false;
         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Message);
   }
   return retBl;
}
```

I would expect it to create a new user but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for `CREATE USER` command I don't think you can pass command parameter likewise. Rather substitute the value as is like below using string interpolation syntax.

```
string query = $"CREATE USER '{name}@{host} IDENTIFIED BY {password}";
```

For an older C# version consider using `string.Format()`

```
string query = string.Format("CREATE USER '{0}'@'{1}' IDENTIFIED BY '{2}'",name,host,password);
```

Per OP's comment: You can't cause it's not a DML operation. If you are worried about *SQL Injection* probably cause input value is coming from user input then you will have sanitize it someway and moreover if you observe the input are quoted.

Again, I would suggest that this kind of admin operation should go in a DB bootstrap script and not in your application code.

Comment: But it wouldn't be save for SQLInjection like this, right? and is there a reason why i shuldn't be able to use parameters for CREATE USER ?

Comment: `is there a reason why i shuldn't be able to use parameters for CREATE USER ?` Because it doesn't work.

Comment: Do note that single quotes in those variables would break your sentence, some replace or scape would be needed

Comment: @bradbury9 no it shouldn't. See another similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460954/c-sharp-mysql-create-user

Comment: @bradbury9 makes sence, thought to look at it with replacing the parameters with the values, but if you look at it with the parameters and assume the parameters just have a different meaning it is logical for me. Thanks for the advise

Comment: @Rahul did see that post but i assumed i can make it more save with the parameters and wonderd why it didnt worked. So i did test this but just was sure it shuld work with parameters. (still duplicate? hope not)